# GPS not working on Samsung after Android 10 update

Tags: samsung, gps

Since the update GPS stops working most of the time.

I have an A6, but it's a widespread problem on many Samsung devices.

I only found a workaround so far:

> work-around until Samsung fixes it.  Download and install "GPSTest".   Once installed, turn off mobile data, open GPSTest and it will get a GPS signal with coordinates.  Turn mobile data back on, then hit the home button and open whatever app you want.  Basicaly GPSTest keeps the GPS alive and it will allow other apps to function as well.  I have to do this almost every time I need to use a GPS app.  It works, but is a pain...

Source: https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S9/GPS-not-available-after-Android-10-update/td-p/1101309

But this works only sometimes.

Is there a better way to fix GPS? Or is there a reliable way to apply that workaround?